# Unable to match a simple assignment in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an input pattern to match:

```
identifier=apple-packs/apple-packages-extension/albama_togo_air_extension
```

My grammar definition in ANTLR4 looks like this:
grammar MyDSL;

```
@lexer::members {
    public static final int WHITESPACE = 1;
    public static final int COMMENTS = 2;
}
locationReference
    : ID '=' genericstring ';';

ID:LETTER (LETTER | [0-9])*;
genericstring:(.)+?;
```

The issue faced:
line 1:16 token recognition error at: '-'
line 1:22 token recognition error at: '/'
line 1:28 token recognition error at: '-'
...
I suppose my grammar is unable to match special characters by the parser rule:
genericstring:(.)+?;
I had also understood "." means any character.

Comment: I had missed ";" in the input string. The question should read as:identifier=apple-packs/apple-packages-extension/albama_togo_air_extension;

Comment: Even with ";" added the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

In a lexer rule `.` matches any character. In a parser rule, `.` matches any token.

Note, `token recognition` errors are generated by the lexer; in this case because the lexer has no rule to match a `-`.